# Drain line under drag chute door of F-4 phantom

Tags: feature-identification, f-4

What is this drain line under the drag chute door on the F-4?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Page 2-4 of the USAF's [TO 1F-4E-1, F-4E Flight Manual](http://www.f4phantom.com/docs/F4Manual-1979-T-O-1F-4E-1-Flight-Manual-USAF-Series-F-4E-Aircraft.pdf), describes it as a "Fuselage Cell Cavity Drain" in the pre-flight inspection checklist. It says that if you find a puddle of fuel, dripping from the drain or any evidence of recent leakage, it could mean one or more of the aircraft's fuel cells could be damaged and should be "cause for concern."

In the F-4 the fuel is stored in 7 cells at the top of the fuselage, from behind the cockpit to about the location of the exhaust, as well as wing fuel tanks, as shown in the diagram below. If any cell is leaking, the fuel will accumulate in the cavity where the cells are installed and drain out that pipe. The structure above the drain is the fuel vent mast.

[image: F-4 Exploded Diagram]